# Azure Logic Apps - Workflow Overview Error (Invalid URL)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have configured an Azure Logic-App (Standard-Plan) locally in Visual Studio Code. The build-process and the designer are working fine. I have successfully integrated my own Built-In Custom Connector for my Logic-App. But now I have the problem that i can't open the Overview Section for my Workflows. It says, that an URL is invalid but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Also no HTTP-Trigger were loaded in the "func host start" command.

[image]

What I'm using:

- azure-fucntions-core-tools: 4.0.5095
- dotnet: 7.0.202
- azurite: 3.23.0
- ngrok: 3.2.2

Would be nice if someone could help me with this issue

I changed already the versions of these tools.
I tried a lot of things in the host.json & local.settings.json

Comment: This needs to look from your custom connector end how you have defined the configuration and its better support over one on one by verifying the details. I will suggest you to open a support ticket with us so the team can review it. In case if you don't have the support plan then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it seems like a bug in overview page. Just launch/run the logicapps,then close and re-open the overview again, it shows the url and loads the run history as well. probably, click overview once "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID"

[image]